# Forward A servlet request to a .html file in java?

Tags: java, servlets

Basically I have servlet named `forward`. When a request is made to it, it forwards the request to a .html file like this:

```
@WebServlet("/forward")
public class forward extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/videos/forward.html").forward(request, response);
        return;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I test this on eclipse when a request is made to this servlet, it responds with the link as `localhost/videos/forward.html`

But then when I deployed it with name `com.war` Now when a request is made to it, it responds with `localhost/com/videos/forward.html`

How can I make the requestDispatcher to respond with `localhost/videos/forward.html` and not as `localhost/com/videos/forward.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you cannot. Forwarding is a request made to the servlet container to pass control to another *servlet* in same servlet context. A JSP page in indeed implemented as a servlet, but a HTML is just a ressource, so you cannot forward to it.

But you can *redirect* to it. A redirection works by sending a special response telling the browser that it should go to that other URL. As it works at browser level, you can redirect to a HTML page or even to a completely different site.

You can use the `sendRedirect` method from `HttpServletResponse` to initiate a redirection from a servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/forward")
public class forward extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.sendRedirect("/videos/forward.html");
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: But in their docs, it said "Forwards a request from a servlet to another resource (servlet, JSP file, or HTML file) on the server". link docs => https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.htm

Answer (score 0):

Just write 
response.sendRedirect(pagename.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, u can.
use:

```
RequestDispatcher r = req.getRequestDispatcher(String arg);
```